# sendKeys not working in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, forms, selenium, input, webdriver

Having problems with Webdriver in trying to input text into a form. The form has javascript validation that I can't get rid of. It has an error message enabled by default that only gets removed when valid input is detected (for example if you type IRELAND and press TAB or click away).

Tried using the key.TAB from selenium, didn't work. This is the code:

```
await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className('combi-select__input')), 15000);
const sets = await driver.findElement(By.className('combi-select__input'));

await sets.sendKeys("IRELAND");
```

Now when I check the html output, the form is empty and I still get the error. I tried click() on it first.

On the other hand this works:

```
await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className('combi-select__input')), 15000);
const sets = await driver.findElement(By.className('combi-select__input'));
    
await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','IRELAND');", sets);
```

The problem with this is that the javascript validation still keeps the error, so the form can't be submitted.

If anyone can help, that would be amazing.

Comment: the html output won't change... it sounds like you just want to click on something else (or a matching term?)  Type it in manually and right-click on the input... choose "inspect element" and add the HTML shown there with the surrounding form to your question.

Comment: if you have to you can always generate the blur on that field... https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_blur.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JavascriptExecutor`

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);          
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("useremail"));

jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='-----your input----';", email);
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I did in the example I gave, except that I used the nodeJS version. The input value does get changed, but the error doesn't disappear because it's probably some onchange event triggered on key presses.